# validate URL with DLL from classic ASP

Tags: url, asp-classic

How to validate given URL is valid , it checks the URL validity and retuns the status of the URL like status 200 OK.

Can you anyone help, how to write DLL in C# or vc++

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a DLL for this, just write the function in VB, using the `ServerXMLHTTP` object.